# Is it true that $f(v) \circ T = f(v \circ T)?$

Tags: functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and take $v \in L^1(\Omega)$. Suppose $T:\Gamma\to \Omega$ is a diffeomorphism between two bounded domains. Is it true that
$$f(v) \circ T = f(v \circ T)?$$
i.e. are they the same functions?

I'm a bit confused.. for example $f$ can be a function which is piecewise continuous and it seems strange to me that this identity can be true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as composition of functions is associative.